# Функция с regex, которая вернет акроним по переданной в нее строке со словами[Python]

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Мне нужно написать функцию с регулярными выражениями, которая будет из рандомной строки делать акроним.
Пробую сразу несколько способов, но они все останавливаются на первом слове:

```
import re
def acronym(some_words):
  some_words = 'Информационные технологии'
  for word_pattern in some_words:
    word_pattern_find = re.findall(r'(\w{1})\w+\s+', some_words, flags = re.IGNORECASE)
    word_pattern_search = re.search(r'(\w{1})\w+\s+', some_words, flags = re.IGNORECASE)
    word_sub = re.sub(r'((\w{1})\w+\s+)*', r'\2', some_words)
  print(word_pattern_find)
  print(word_pattern_search.group(1))
  print(word_sub)

acronym(some_words)
```

В результате получается
['И'] \ И \ Итехнологии
соответственно после поиска по строке 'Информационные технологии'.

Я пытаюсь весь шаблон включить в скобочную группу и добавлять квантификаторы вроде *, +, ненужную часть шаблона ставить в скобки с ?= и ?:, но все равно не могу сделать так, чтобы следующие слова тоже сокращались до первого символа. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: `re.findall(r"(?<!\w)\w, str.upper(), re.UNICODE)`  - вернет вам первые найденные буквы слов в массив, для `\w` не нужен ignorcase, но для кириллицы нужен unicode

Comment: @ipatev_nn у вас в регекспе потерялись кавычки и квантификаторы. предлагаю вам оформить комментарий как ответ, но более развернуто.

Comment: @strawdog, о, действительно, не напечатал... Спасибо! `re.findall(r"(?<!\w)\w", str.upper(), re.UNICODE)` а квантификатор не нужен, если делать аббревиатуру, как акроним получать я не знаю, поэтому и в комментарии только пишу)

Comment: @ipatev_nn спасибо!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно добавить `\b` (граница слова) в регулярное выражение

```
import re

def acronym(some_words):
    return ''.join(re.findall(r'\b\w', some_words, flags=re.IGNORECASE)).upper()

some_words = 'Информационные технологии и все такое прочее'
print(acronym(some_words))
```

```
ИТИВТП
```